# Detect if user is a first time visitor, if so, re-direct to page, if not, re-direct to another page

Tags: cookies, redirect, detect

Is there a way to detect if a user is visiting my website for the first time, and if so, redirect them to a page, for example, index-first-time-visitor.php - and if they are not a first time visitor, it sends them to index.php

If there is a way to do this, please demonstrate how.

Comment: Cookies, IP address storage, sessions, etc...  You need to define your architecture a little more.  This is overly broad to get a concrete answer.

Comment: set a cookie to never expire when they visit (give it 9999999999999), if they have the cookie on the second visit, then redirect them to the not-first-time-index.php

its not perfect, because people like to clear their cashes and cookies all the time, but its the best your going to get.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put this at the top of your index.php

```
<?php
if ($_COOKIE['iwashere'] != "yes") { 
  setcookie("iwashere", "yes", time()+315360000);  
  header("Location: http://example.com/index-first-time-visitor.php"); 
}
?>
```

The cookie will live for 10 years, after that, a user will be a "new" visitor again.

Comment: I assume 315360000=10 years. How do you calculate, let's say, 1 month?

Comment: @Talha - Simple math really. 315360000 / 10 = 31,536,000 (1 year). 31,536,000 / 12 = 2,628,000 (1 month).

Comment: @Talha - Or you could use Google - just write: 1 month in seconds