# How can I check if a user is coming from a different page of my website or from another website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I want to make a different animation based on if someone is coming to my webpage from another page on the site, or if they are just coming to the website for the first time.  I basically want to do:

```
if (coming from my page) {
    $(this).css('display': 'block');
    $(this).fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the webserver.

Using PHP, you can access the variable `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`, it has the answer to your questions, but it is not always filled by the User Agent (web browser).

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Using ASP, the variable is: `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")`

- http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Comment: They are using JavaScript, so it would be `document.referrer`.  Reference: [Can I get the referrer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856697/can-i-get-the-referrer)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a script that, selects every `<a>` element on your page.
Then for the `href="some_other_page_on_your_site"` part you alter it like this:

```js
href="some_other_page_on_your_site?coming_from_my_site=true"
```

Then on a page load you have to check if "coming_from_my_site" is included in `document.location.search`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

How if you get your client ip address and insert it to your db,
or you can put cookie. . .

[[Detect if user is a first time visitor, if so, re-direct to page, if not, re-direct to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714522/detect-if-user-is-a-first-time-visitor-if-so-re-direct-to-page-if-not-re-dir][1])

check that problem, I hope that can solve your problem